# How to pass the string with whitespace as a keyword argument?

Tags: python

I am trying to implement the function which gets values and set these values to new values of a dictionary.

```
data = {} 
def setValue(**kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        data[key] = value
```

This function works well for the strings having no whitespace.

```
setValue(Hello = 3)
# {'Hello': 3}
```

But when I tried to set the value of key string having whitespace like "Hello World", there was SyntaxError.

```
setValue(Hello World = 3) # SyntaxError: invalid syntax
setValue("Hello World" = 3) # SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

How to pass a string having whitespace characters as a keyword argument?

Comment: Would using `Hello_World` be an acceptable implementation instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to pass a string having whitespace characters as a keyword argument?

This is not possible, since variables (and thus keyword arguments) can't have whitespace in Python.

Source:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

You could use underscores:

```
setValue(Hello_World=3)
```

Or pass the kwargs as a dict:

```
setValue(**{'Hello World': 3})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a dict of keyword arguments.

```
k = {'Hello World': 3}
setValue(**k)
```