# Create dict object using space in key name

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a way to create a dict object with a space in the key?

```
# This way works

>>> d = {'a b': 1}
>>> d
{'a b': 1}
```

```
# Is it possible to create the same using this method?

>>> d = dict('a b'=1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Comment: Related:[How to pass the string with whitespace as a keyword argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55581347/how-to-pass-the-string-with-whitespace-as-a-keyword-argument). Another option is to pass a list of tuples: `dict([('a b', 1)])`.

Comment: Are you somehow under the impression that `{'a b': 1}` is *not* a dict object with a space in the key?

Comment: I prefer to use dict() because I find it easier/cleaner when there are many items to write out.
Also for the sake of consistency throughout the code, but I guess it's really not a big deal just curious. Is one way considered more proper than the other?

Comment: @kav if you want to use the `dict(key=value)` form, then `key` **must** be a valid identifier. `a b` is not a valid identifier, it would be parsed as two identifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this manner of constructing a dictionary cannot handle a key with a space.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict shows numerous methods for constructing dictionaries.  The first one is what you're trying to do:

```
a = dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)
```

But the following note says:

> Providing keyword arguments as in the first example only works for
> keys that are valid Python identifiers.

A string value, as you're trying, is not a valid identifier.  And an identifier cannot includes spaces, so `a b` without quotes will not work either.